# How can a Pure Titans recover the full body after extended period?

Tags: attack-on-titan

It is said that Ymir spent about 60 years in Pure Titan form. It is also said that Pure Titan only have original subject's spine instead of full body like one of Nine ([see ref [25] here or search word "spine" if number shifts](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Titan)).

So, how exactly she could recover back to complete human with brain, conciousness and memories while turning into one of Nine? Other transformations explicitly shown or mentioned so far generally only take less than hour between turning human into Pure and upgrading to Nine, so it less of a concern, but 60 years? Shouldn't pretty much of whatever was original Ymir be long lost by then?

Answer (score 1):

**That is outdated information.** It was revealed later on in the series that Pure Titans are humans who transformed into Titans. *They were not absorbed, they transformed, notice the difference*. Their body parts, brain and all, just got bigger. Their transformation to pure Titans, however, limit their ability to think although it does not mean that it completely eradicates their brain. If I were to speculate, I believe something in their transformation causes a part of their brain to be 'locked out' and can only be accessed once they consume another Titan Shifter.

Official information about this from the manga, though, is yet to be revealed. But what we do know is that *Titans have regeneration abilities and immortality*. **So, no, the original Ymir would not be long lost by then.**

Comment: This would seem contradicted by the many images of human bodies poking out of the napes of the nine titans and those showing the Human inside a titan thinking about what to do. Like [these](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBD_en-GBGB843GB843&biw=1280&bih=610&tbm=isch&sxsrf=ACYBGNSOVgV-rzguazggDGzokUn7Zno3sQ%3A1569576608175&sa=1&ei=oNaNXe6oCoHCkwWn8pSIBw&q=Image+of+Eren+inside+a+titan&oq=Image+of+Eren+inside+a+titan&gs_l=img.3...45260.50530..50741...0.0..0.431.5512.0j22j3j0j3......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......35i39j0j0i10.v5eBoyquGxM&ved=0ahUKEwju-LXB2PDkAhUB4aQKHSc5BXEQ4dUDCAc&uact=5)

Comment: @Jontia Pure titans and the nine Titan Shifters are different. In Pure Titans, Hange was never able to find a human residing in the nape, like with Titan Shifters. Only the Titan Shifters have humans in them in the nape. Please understand that I am talking about the Pure Titans that cannot transform and has no mind of their own, which is vastly different than Titan Shifters.

Comment: @Jontia Eren is a Titan Shifter, not a Pure Titan so I don't see how this contradicts my answer. For reference, may I ask up to which chapter have you read in the manga? So that I can maybe avoid spoilers in case it's still not clear.

Comment: I'm anime rather than manga. But the growth transformation doesn't seem to fit for either Shifters or Pure titans. Shifters obviously have the human body still present. If Pures were growth transformation, there's no reason for the nape/weakspot to be so small and specific.

Comment: @Jontia Then, again, it was shown in the manga how Hange never found anything in the nape when they opened one. Check Chapter 51. It was speculated that there was something in there that is 'probably' a part of human that acts as control center for Pure Titans but it was never really clarified since the physiology of Pure Titans was never discussed that much. It was only up to speculation by Hange.

Comment: The link in the question points at Chapter 51, it is something I will check out when I get a chance. But ultimately that is the root of the question. If the human body of a pure is gone, how do they get it back when eating a shifter? Titan Regeneration seems like a reasonable answer. Well as reasonable as people turning into Titans in the first place anyway...

Comment: @Jontia That is something that is never answered in the manga, if I recall correctly. Which was why I presented a possible explanation, although I admit it is somewhat vague. Who knows, I could be wrong when new chapters explaining it would come out :)

Comment: use spoiler tag maybe ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no specification on the manga or anime about that. But it seems that any "pure" titan as long it gets the spinal fluid of 1/9 titans is able to go back to being a human no matter how long it takes then in their pure titan form. Yet again, all of Ymir's people seem to see the invisible roads or at least the people that turn into one of the  1/9 titans. Time pass different in that place, seems to take years or thousands of years[forever]. Ymir, just mentioned that it was like a never ending nightmare to be in the pure titan form.

Another way of putting it is, all pure titans are female eggs, and the 1/9 are the sperm, when of of the 1/9 titan gets eaten by an egg, it becomes a human, no matter how long it was in that place.

Answer (score 0):

In the manga chapter 115 page 40, after Zeke ...

> .. almost lost all of his lower body, his body got regenerated by founder Ymir in the path.

Later in chapter 120 page 17, in a conversation between Zeke and Eren, Zeke says that ...

> founder Ymir has been here (path) for over 2 thousand years even after her death and making titan body for them.